# BlasNotFoundError when installing Scipy through pip

Tags: python

I'm trying to install Scipy in a virtual env through pip and I'm getting an error that says `numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError`
I've never run into this before and I installed numpy from pip, so it should've installed everything correctly. I looked on the Blas website and I could only find a version for FORTRAN and I don't know if that's what I need. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, BLAS is written in FORTRAN. You need the shared library.

Comment: I downloaded the tar with the FORTRAn files. How do I install it as a shared library? Or am I looking for something else?

Comment: What distro are you using? It's probably in the repositories tbh.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're on Raspbian, install the package `libblas-dev` though apt. It should work fine after that.

Comment: I additionally had to install `gfortran`, `libopenblas-base` and `libatlas-base-dev` to make it work.